# I am trying to make word1 from the letters of word2 in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, string-comparison, string-length

```
word1 = input() 
word2 = input()
a = len(word2)
b = len(word1)
count = b
while (word2[a-1] == word1[b-1]):
    count-=1
    a -= 1
    if count == 0:
        break
    else:
        print('it cant be made')
b-=1
print('it can be made')
```

What I am trying to do is compare the last letter of word2 to the last letter of word 1 and if they are equal, - the count by 1 and move down a letter in word 2 until the count is == to 0 therefore suggesting the word can be made.
if the 2 letters aren't equal it should just move onto the next letter of word1 and repeat the process. if the the count doesn't reach 0 then the word can't be made because it is the Len of the word you are trying to make.

This is what happens when I run the code:

```
bru
kinn
it can be made
>>> 
= RESTART: /Users/nicksuciu/Documents/python work/section b make word from word2.py
bru
kibun
it can be made
>>> 
= RESTART: /Users/nicksuciu/Documents/python work/section b make word from word2.py
bru
kibun
it can be made
>>>
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Are you having  a problem with this code? What is the problem? Please include your test input and expected results.

Comment: sorry i'm new to stack overflow, basically it doesn't work and only prints that it can be made no matter what

Comment: so my desired output is for it to be able to know whether my word1 can be made from word2 and to say it. so if yes then print ' it can be made' but if no 'it can't be made'. The problem I believe I am facing is that I don't think comparing the strings is correct, but there aren't any errors so I don't know what is actually going wrong

Comment: Just as an FYI for future questions, when someone asks you to state sample input and your desired output, they're not asking you to describe in words what you want the code to do, they're asking for an actual test case. For example: for inputs "cat" and "carpet", I want the result to be "it can be made" (because all the letters of "cat" appear in the word "carpet") but the code results in "it can't be made". Most of the time, you should include the input and desired output in your original question.

Comment: oh ok, I understand. Thank you for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of your test cases, the `while` loop immediately exits because the last letters aren't equal.  The way your code is written, the result after finishing the `while` is to print "it can be made" before exiting, regardless of what happened inside the loop, so you will always get that output.

Solving this problem by doing a single iteration through both words together is difficult because presumably the letters might be in different orders; you're likely to "miss" a letter in many cases.  The simpler solution is to use dicts to count up the letters in each word and then compare the counts.  Here's an example using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

word1 = Counter(input())
word2 = Counter(input())
if all(word2[char] >= word1[char] for char in word1):
    print('it can be made')
else:
    print('it cant be made')
```

```
>python test.py
bru
kibun
it cant be made

>python test.py
bru
kribun
it can be made
```